# Preventing native memory leak by customizing garbage collector?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native

Let's say I'm writing an API in java that refers to some native C libraries, that requires destructors to be called explicitly. If the destructors are not called, I run out of native memory.

Is there a way to protect users of my API from calling the destructors explicitly, by having the garbage collector call the destructors somehow? (perhaps based on some estimate I make of the size of the used native memory?)

I know Java doesn't have its garbage collector as part of the Java API, but perhaps there is some way to get this implemented?

Comment: This is one use case where defining `.finalize()` on your Java objects is actually useful! Destroy native objects in it. Also provide a method so that a user can do it itself (and yell in `finalize()` if the method wasn't called, that'll teach them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative if you have control over creation of your objects is to reference them with a WeakReference using the constructor that takes a ReferenceQueue. When they get out of scope, the Reference will be queued and you can have your own thread polling the queue and call some clean up function.

Why? 
Well, it is slightly more efficient than adding finalizers to your classes (because it forces the gc to do some special handling of them).

**Edit**: The following two (variations of the same article) describes it:
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/finalization/ 
http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/30192

Peter Lawrey has a very good point when he says:

> Even so, waiting for the GC to cleanup can be inefficient and you may want to expose a means of explicitly cleaning up the resource if its required.

Whenever you can assume your users to be on Java7, take a look at [java.lang.AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) as it will help them do that automatically when using the new try-with-resources.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to use finalize(), you may need to trigger a GC if you run out of resources to make the call, however a GC hasn't been run.

The ByteBuffer.allocateDirect() has this issue.  It need the GC to clean up its ByteBuffers, However, you can reach your maximum direct memory before a GC is triggered, so the code has to detect this and triggers a `System.gc()` explicitly.

Even so, waiting for the GC to cleanup can be inefficient and you may want to expose a means of explicitly cleaning up the resource if its required.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collector will call `finalize()` of Java objects when the Java object is about to be GCd, and inside the finalize, you could call the destructor. Just make a *new* Java object for every destructor that needs to be called, and keep reference to that Java object until when you want to call the destructor.

In practice, `finalize()` will be called sooner or later (even though technically Java makes no guarantee that any particular object will *ever* be GCd). The only exception is if the object is still around when the process is shutting down: then it may indeed never get GCd.